# В чем ошибка моего ответа на данный вопрос про местоимения

Tags: местоимения, егэ, тесты

[image: Скриншот ошибки и текст задания]
Вопрос звучал так:
"Самостоятельно подберите указательное местоимение, которое должно стоять на месте пропуска в третьем (3) предложении текста. Запишите это местоимение".

Хочу узнать – мой вариант ответа допустим и просто не предполагался программой? Или тут действительно есть ошибка – и если да, то какая.

Comment: данных - не местоимение(, от слова дать, отглагольное что-то. Местоимения отглагольными не бывают, они бывают только от местоиметльными. Глагол от местоимения можно образовать, например, тыкать - говорить ты кому-то, но, как видите, это совсем не слово данных, данные.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибка только в том, что слово [**данный**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) в этом контексте является прилагательным, а нужно было подобрать [**указательное местоимение**](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть здесь слово "данных" - является причастием? Форма "данный" может быть местоимением? И даже если да, то это будет НЕ указательное местоимение - я верно понял?

Comment: @GelaChrikishvili Нет, здесь "данных" – прилагательное, местоименное прилагательное. По смыслу оно очень близко указательному местоимению "этот", является его синонимом, но по  классифицикации к местоимениям не относится. // Причастие, например, здесь: "Упражнение, данное нам учителем, было выполнено".

Comment: Автор вопроса, я так понимаю, пока не имеет права отметить полезность твоего ответа. Надо это исправить...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова   Всем данке, сенкью и мерси!

Answer (score 1):

> Хочу узнать – мой вариант ответа допустим и просто не предполагался
> программой?

**Думаю, что именно так всё и обстоит.**

Кем-то утверждённого перечня местоимений не существует.  В каких-то словарях «данный» называется прилагательным. Но составители задания должны были бы знать, что и Зализняк, и ряд других грамматистов слово «данный» в значении «этот» считают местоимением.

Вот как, к примеру, квалифицирует слово «данный»  ***«Большой универсальный словарь русского языка» под ред. В.В. Морковкина*** (о словаре см. [здесь](https://paraknig.me/view/2171247)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотрите, в чем проблема. Есть местоимения, которые произошли от морфем местоимений - указательных слов: то, к+то, всё, сам, и тд.. А есть псевдоместоимения, которые произошли, например любой - любый мной, то есть это не совсем местоимения, а словосочетания, у которых убрано местоимение и заменено окончание. Думаю, что в данном(данном мной) случае вы ошибаетесь. А данным(страдательное прич) - будет данным кому-то. Разница в окончании данном/данным от того кто дал/ кому дали. С настоящими местоимениями такого не получится. С такой логикой можно все страдательные причастия превратить в синонимы.

Comment: @Ivan Olshansky Есть способ словообразования с помощью окончаний?

Comment: @Буратино: «*Думаю, что в данном (данном мной) случае вы ошибаетесь*» === Ошибки у меня нет. Я лишь привёл ссылку на лингвистов, имеющих иное, чем у других лингвистов, мнение на состав указательных местоимений в русском языке.

Ошибка есть в одном из комментариев в этой теме: «*здесь "данных" – прилагательное, **местоименное прилагательное**. По смыслу оно очень близко указательному местоимению "этот", является его синонимом, но по классифицикации к местоимениям не относится*».

Comment: Если местоименные прилагательные не считать местоимениями, то нельзя считать местоимениями и слова **«тот», «этот», «такой», «таков»**.  Ведь у Зализняка в его «Грамматическом словаре русского языка» все (!) эти слова приведены с пометой «мс-п» (местоименное прилагательное).

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что прямо у вас ошибка, я говорю что проблема так не решается в принципе, потому что местоименные прилагательные совсем не местоимения и несут окраску взаимодействия, в то время как местоимения этим не отличаются. Почему оно прилагательное тоже тот еще вопрос, если оно отглагольное. Местоимения это что-то что есть без взаимодействия. Тот, этот, та-ков, та-кой. Это все от То-Та -указаний на предмет, а не про взаимодействие. Я не знаю почему у Зализняка это мс-п. Я указывают лишь указывают, что логика мне пока не понятна, но я тупой, поэтому может дело во мне и проблемы нет.

Comment: Как вариант я подробнее изложил сомнения в своем ответе, меня такая логика устраивает пока, но она, конечно, не имеет отношения к русской грамматике.

Comment: @Буратино: *Я не знаю почему у Зализняка это мс-п.* === Не только у Зализняка.

Из «*Грамматики русского языка*» под ред. Виноградова (1960): § 628. В зависимости от того, указывают ли местоимения на предмет (лицо) или его качество, а также в зависимости от характера словоизменения и грамматических связей с другими словами все местоимения делятся на **местоименные существительные** (*я, ты*…) и **местоименные прилагательные** (*мой, твой, наш, ваш, свой*, ***какой, каков***, *который, чей*, ***тот, этот***…).

Comment: Ой не, спасибо, но эта таксономия не для меня, я иду другим путём).  Проблема в том, что без местоимения вы вопрос к слову не зададите, то есть не определите прилагательное оно или глагол. Л-логика. Как местоимение может быть прилагательным, если оно само на себя замкнуто в вопросе?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я предлагаю трансморфемные слова типа другой, любой, данной(данная) - назвать притяжательными причастиями, причастиями играющими роль местоимений, указательных чаще всего, образованных с помощью "редуцирования" местоимения в словосочетании: любой - любый мной/тобой, данной/данная - данный мной, другой - дружащий с ним. Иначе логика словообразования с помощью изменения окончания отсутствует. Вряд ли у кого-то язык повернется образовать личное местоимение "данное".

Такие псевдоместоимения, не имеющие морфемной связи с именительными местоимениями Я, Ты , Он и тд, возвратным Сам и указательными Кто, Что, Всё, Это, ну и тд, а произведенные от глаголов дружить, давать, любить и тд., нарушают логику восприятия этих местоимений. Так что я согласен с составителями ЕГЭ, что слово "данных"(явно образованное от глагола "дать") - не подходит, а слово "этих"(от местоимения "это") - является правильным ответом без нареканий.

Ваша ошибка в том, что выбирать нужно те ответы, к которым не придраться, во избежание разночтений. Конечно, вы можете подать апелляцию, но нужен ли вам дополнительный геморрой с неизвестным исходом? С системой нет смысла спорить, ваша задача понимать алгоритм, который лежит в основе её функционирования и уметь использовать его в своих целях - это основной навык, которому обучают в школе и проверяют на ЕГЭ и прочих тестах, к научному знанию отношения не имеющий.

Поспорить вы можете с живым человеком, со мной, что я написал какую-то чепуху. А с системой смысла спорить нет, потому что она в принципе вас не видит. То что система считает правильным, это лишь её собственное отражение, она не способна увидеть ваше понимание, она лишь способна соотнести полученную информацию со своей базой данных. В то время как ваши знания и понимание могут лежать(и должны быть) в том числе и вне области базы данных системы. Иначе смысла в этом нет никакого, так как система уже решает подобные задачи с помощью роботов, ИИ, чат-ботов - живые люди для этого уже почти тут не нужны, она сама может намного эффективнее отражать себя в окружающих предметах, чем люди, которые пытаются скопировать её базы данных в свой мозг.